# How to make a class table member distinct in Lua objects?

Tags: lua

Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

local field = 
{
    name = '',
    array = {},

    new = function(self, o)
        o = o or {}
        setmetatable(o, self)
        self.__index = self
        return o
    end,
}

local fld1 = field:new()
local fld2 = field:new()

fld1.name = 'hello'
table.insert(fld1.array, 1)
table.insert(fld1.array, 2)
table.insert(fld1.array, 3)

fld2.name = 'me'
table.insert(fld2.array, 4)
table.insert(fld2.array, 5)

print('fld1: name='..fld1.name..' len='..#fld1.array)
print('fld2: name='..fld2.name..' len='..#fld2.array)
```

The output when executed is as follows:

```
fld1: name=hello len=5
fld2: name=me len=5
```

From the output, it can be seen that `name` has different values in `fld1` and `fld2`. `array`, however, has the same value in `fld1` and `fld2` (`fld1.array` and `fld2.array` are the same and therefore have the same length of 5).

How do I fix this code so that `fld1.array` is independent of `fld2.array` (so that modifying `fld1.array` does not change `fld2.array`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `fld1` and `fld2` have distinct names because you *gave* them distinct names - their own properties.

When you perform table key assignment the new key and value are stored directly in the table that you specify. The `__index` metamethod only comes in to play when you perform table key *lookup* and the key is not found in the table.

A quick example where we can see that table key assignment will *shadow* keys in the `__index` lookup chain.

```
local Foo = { shared = 'shared', private = 'private' }
Foo.__index = Foo

local foo = setmetatable({}, Foo)

foo.private = 'a shadowed value'

print(Foo.shared, foo.shared) -- shared shared
print(Foo.private, foo.private) -- private  a shadowed value
```

*Note: there is a `__newindex` metamethod for catching table key assignment that involves a never-before-seen key.*

Consider treating the `new` method more like a traditional constructor function, wherein you assign 'private' properties to newly created *instances*.

```
local Field = {
    -- shared properties go here
}

-- shared methods are defined as such

function Field:new (name)
    local o = {
        -- private properties for the newly created object go here
        name = name or '',
        array = {}
    }

    self.__index = self

    return setmetatable(o, self)
end

function Field:insert (value)
    table.insert(self.array, value)
end

local fld1 = Field:new('hello')
local fld2 = Field:new('me')

fld1:insert(1)
fld1:insert(2)
fld1:insert(3)

fld2:insert(4)
fld2:insert(5)

print('fld1: name='..fld1.name..' len='..#fld1.array) -- fld1: name=hello len=3
print('fld2: name='..fld2.name..' len='..#fld2.array) -- fld2: name=me len=2
```

Some more notes:

- Generally, 'class' names should be in PascalCase, to make them distinct.
- Having a `:new` function in the lookup chain means *instances* can invoke it, this may or may not be desirable. (Can create slightly ugly inheritance this way.)
- There is a difference between how you define methods which use the implicit `self`. You should give [Chapter 16 of Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html#16) a read. It might be a tad dated if you're using 5.2 or 5.3, but it should still have a lots of useful information.
- If you're interested in a tiny library for this, I recently wrote [Base](https://github.com/Okahyphen/base). If you look around, you'll find lots of little OOP packages for making these kinds of things a bit easier.

Answer (score -1):

Lua's oop technic not same c++, java

__index metamethod reference target table record.

and so, fld1, fld2 array item is Field's array item.

you must make a new table and use it.

why name's value different. Because, Your assign a name

> fld1.name = 'hello'

simply code fix

```
fld1.array = {}
```

using new method code fix

```
local o1 = {name = '', array = {}}
local o2 = {name = '', array = {}}

local fld1 = field:new(o1)
local fld2 = field:new(o2)
```

make new table(make o) and insert **new** method.